# Testing for lack of associated objects in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This follows on from an earlier question as I am bending my brain around Ruby on Rails.

I have items which are displayed on a webpage, depending on whether their status allows the display or not, using a named scope - if the document status ("For Sale", "Sold", "Deleted" etc) has the show_latest_items flag set to 1, it will allow associated items to be displayed on the page :

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :status
  scope :show_latest_items, joins(:status).where(:statuses => {:show_latest_items => ["1"]})
end

class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end
```

This is how it is displayed currently

```
<% latest_items = Items.show_latest_items.last(30) %>
<% latest_items.each do |i| %>
  :
<% end %>
```

So this is all well and good, but I now want to only display the item if it has an associated photo.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_photos
end

class ItemPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end
```

So in my mind, I should, using the named scope, be able to pull back a list of Items for display, and then filter them using .present?  or .any? methods.  Curious thing is this:

```
<% latest_items = Items.show_latest_items.where(:item_photos.any?).last(30) %>
```

returns an error:

```
undefined method `any?' for :item_photos:Symbol
```

Whereas:

```
<% latest_items = Items.show_latest_items.where(:item_photos.present?).last(30) %>
```

doesn't error, but it doesn't filter out items with no photos, either.

I've tried various other methods, as well as trying to do custom finders, writing names scopes for photos, but nothing is making a lot of sense.  Should I be approaching this from a different angle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:item_photos.any?
```

This doesn't work because Ruby's [Symbol](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html) has no `any?` method.

```
.where(:item_photos.present?)
```

This doesn't do the filtering you're after because you're calling [`.present?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F) on the Symbol `:item_photos` which evaluates to `true`, making the condition really

```
.where(true)
```

Try simply

```
<% latest_items = Items.show_latest_items.joins(:item_photos).last(30) %>
```

The SQL for this `.joins(:item_photos)` is going to be an `INNER JOIN`, causing `Item` instances with no associated `ItemPhoto` instances to be omitted from the result.

Comment: Works like a dream and beautifully explained. Thank you! (I have got soo much to learn...)

Comment: Ah, one side effect: if there is more than one photo, it joins multiple times and so returns the row item multiple times.

Comment: You can try adding something like `.group("items.id")` before the `.last(30)`

Comment: And just to explain that: Anything wrapped in quotes like `"items.id"` above is sent unmodified to the SQL query Rails generates. This will add `GROUP BY items.id`, which should get you what you're after.